# How to disable default cursor on transparent titlebar of NSWindow?

Tags: macos, user-interface, cocoa

I create a NSWindow with transparent title using:

- setTitleVisibility:NSWindowTitleHidden
- setTitlebarAppearsTransparent:YES
- setMovable:NO

and the style includes NSWindowStyleMaskFullSizeContentView. The window becomes title-less, zoom and fullscreen modes work well. Everything is ok, except the mouse cursor. It becomes the default one when I move it to the area where titlebar would be located if it was visible.

Is it possible to override this behavior so that the mouse cursor shape will be defined by the window content (which uses addCursorRect)?

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between a transparent titlebar and no titlebar at all. It sounds like you have a window with a transparent titlebar, but you want a window with no titlebar.

If you want no titlebar at all, you need to make sure the window's `styleMask` does not have `NSWindowStyleMaskTitled`.

If you create the window in a xib or storyboard, you can turn off the “Title Bar” checkbox in the window's Attributes inspector.

If you create the window in code, you can set the `styleMask` using the `initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:` initializer, or you can set the `styleMask` after creation.

For example, this line will remove the `NSWindowStyleMaskTitled` bit from an existing window's `styleMask`:

```
self.window.styleMask &= ~NSWindowSytleMaskTitled;
```

Comment: That's what I did at last. But there are a few differences: the window corners become sharp (not round), the window loses the abilities to zoom, minimize and close in the normal way.